# Responsive fixed position element relative to container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want an element to maintain its position while scrolling but only as long as much as the height of the container element.

I found a good answer with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/R8bUQ/

But I want to know if there is a way to do it without specifying the height of the container element to make it responsive.

Here's the failing attempt... The element keeps showing outside the container!

```js
$parent = $('.container');
$elem = $parent.find('div');

$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  $elem.css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
div.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div.outer-div {
  min-height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <p>Another content inside container</p>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  Another outer content. Element should not show over this div.
</div>
```

Comment: It can not be done with pure CSS and HTML if you want to strictly do it the way you are showing us at the moment. There are other ways to achieve that without the use of JS but that require to change your HTML and CSS. Are you open to any major changes?

Comment: It is little unclear what end result you would like to achieve. You need to specify an if statement in your javascript to know how much pixels has been scrolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding condition in your js code to check that inner element is not going out of the parent.

```js
$parent = $('.container');
$elem = $parent.find('.element');
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (($(window).scrollTop() + $elem.height()) < ($parent.offset().top + $parent.height())) {
    $elem.css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
  }
}).trigger('scroll');
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}

div.container {
  position: relative;
}

div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div.outer-div {
  min-height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
body,p { margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <p>Another content inside container</p>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  Another outer content. Element should not show over this div.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading you question again. If i understood what you want to achieve then it is the following:

Make an inner element of a given container be fixed but to the window scrollbar

That can be done without JS. That is, with pure CSS and HTML.

**The sticky way:**
More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
div.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: sticky;  
  margin: 0;
  top: 80px;

}
div.outer-div {
  min-height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <p>Another content inside container</p>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  Another outer content. Element should not show over this div.
</div>
```

Notice who there is only two slight changse at `div .element`

From

```
div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

To

```
div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: sticky;  
  margin: 0;
  top: 80px;
}
```

`postiion` and `top` were changed. You can see why at the link i gave you above.

**If you want element to stay at the top of the viewable part of the container then set `top` to `0px`**

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}
div.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
div .element {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0f0;
  position: sticky;  
  margin: 0;
  top: 0px;

}
div.outer-div {
  min-height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <p>Another content inside container</p>
</div>
<div class="outer-div">
  Another outer content. Element should not show over this div.
</div>
```